# SharePoint: PowerApps, PowerAutomate. Text field information disappears when record is modified/updated

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

I currently have the following builds connected to my SharePoint list:

PowerAutomate:  When a new email arrives in the Outlook create a record in SharePoint list.  The body of the email is captured in a text field/column named 'EmailTxt' in the list.

PowerApps:  Upgraded the standard SharePoint form to a PowerApp

The flow and app work just fine where it brings all data in without issue.  The problem lies when the record is updated/modified using PowerApp.  Any changes or updates using the PowerApp results to the text 'EmailTxt' field clearing out.  I'm wondering if this has to do with they 'OnChange' set to False but I'm unsure how to resolve.

*This does not happen when the record is updated/modified in the SP list itself using grid view.

Answer (score 0):

I'd definitely make sure the Update property of the EmailTxt data card is bound to the text input's Text property, which in turn has Parent.Default in its own Default property.